# EitherT[Option, A, B] === Option[Either[A,B]]

Tags: scala, scalaz

If I understand correctly `EitherT[Option,A,B`] should be identical to `Option[Either[A,B]]`, but the compiler doesn't agree.  The following code fails to compile:

```
def f[A,B] = implicitly[EitherT[Option, A, B] === Option[Either[A,B]]]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: the === you are using there is the one from Leibniz? or where?

Answer (score 8):

They are isomorphic, but not the same value. `EitherT[Option,A,B]` wraps a value of type `Option[Either[A,B]]` in order to provide different behavior. Let's look at the definition:

```
final case class EitherT[F[_], A, B](run: F[A \/ B])
```

So `EitherT` here is wrapping an Option, and the value named `run` is a value which is of type `Option[Either[A,B]]`

Comment: Thanks, stew. Yes === is leibniz